# Native Module to detect Shake for react-native

Tags: swift, react-native

I am trying to implement a native module to detect a shake event for my react native application. I understand that in swift this would be done with the following approach:

```
override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if motion == .MotionShake {
      print("Shake")
    }
  }
```

However, because I am doing this as a Native module and therefore I am not using the UiViewController I am struggling to understand how I do this and what I should be overriding. I am new to Swift so this may be a basic misunderstanding but I have spent quite some time trying to understand this.